# Image upload with angularjs and spring boot

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot

I'm trying to upload an image from an angularjs application to a Spring Boot endpoint, but I'm having the problem below:

```
{"timestamp":1522031262882,"status":400,"error":"Bad Request","exception":"org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException","message":"Required request part 'image' is not present","path":"/customer/uploadLogo"}
```

Angularjs code:

```
function uploadLogo(formdata) {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('image', $scope.picture);

    return $http.post(defaultConfig.baseUrl + 'customer/uploadLogo', formdata, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined},
    });
}
```

Spring-boot code:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/uploadLogo")
public void uploadLogo(@RequestParam("image") MultipartFile file) {
    System.out.println("");
}
```

I'm passing "image" on formData, so this exception does not make much sense to me. Has anyone ever had anything like this?

Comment: Since this is a HTTP Post, your parameter should reference to the [@RequestBody] and not [@RequestParam].

Comment: I think that because I'm sending a form-date, the endpoint must be mapped with RequestParam itself

Comment: Solved, the error happened because $ scope.picture was not a File object